# Express cookieSession key not showing in data headers

Tags: node.js, express, session, socket.io, node.js-connect

I'm trying to solve the infamous problem of accessing session variables within socket.io. I've read basically every link on Google concerning the topic, and I'm still struggling.

After all my routing I have this:

```
io.set('authorization', function(data,accept)
{
    data.cookie = cookie.parse(data.headers.cookie);
    ---> console.log(data.cookie);
    data.sessionID = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(data.cookie['express.sid'].split('.')[0].substring(2), conf.sessionSecret);

    sessionStore.get(data.sessionID, function (err, session)
    {
        console.log(session);
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, the console.log that I drew an arrow to returns this:

```
{ 'connect.sid': 's:3pIi31DPthO8KVOjqzYpeL75.nHvKOpMZsUsyto7CtBJgcJZIiBSN+IC2/aD0GcfYftU' }
```

So of course, I get an error about express.sid being undefined.
When I change express.sid to connect.sid, my session variables are undefined.

I'm really struggling to solve this problem- I've been at it for a few hours. Any help?

EDIT:
To summarize my resolved issues:

1. In app.config I was using cookieSession instead of session.
2. My client was connecting to a port-forwarded, external IP version of my server. This wasn't carrying cookie data.
3. .split('.')[0].substring(2) is absolutely necessary when finding the sessionID.
4. At the end of io.set('authorization, function (handshake,callback), you must call "callback(null,true)" in order for the socket.io connection to proceed normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close. You actually don't need to modify the cookie before it's passed to the parser.

```
io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
  handshake.cookie = cookie.parse(handshake.headers.cookie);
  handshake.sessionID = connect.utils.parseSignedCookie(handshake.cookie['express.sid'], conf.sessionSecret);

  sessionStore.get(handshake.sessionID, function(err, session) {
    // the session would be here
  });
});
```

However, since you have access to the cookie parser middleware, I would personally do this:

```
var parseCookie = express.cookieParser(conf.sessionSecret);
io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
  if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
    parseCookie(handshake, null, function(err) {
      handshake.sessionID = handshake.signedCookies['express.sid'];
      sessionStore.get(handshake.sessionID, function(err, session) {
        // the session would be here
      });
    });
  }
});
```

This approach collects any errors that are possible during the parsing of the cookie, and works by passing the `handshake` object as if it were a HTTP request object, since they both have the `headers.cookie` property. The cookie parser will then parse the cookies and assign them to the `handshake` object, so you can then find the session ID from `handshake.signedCookies`.

Comment: Ah yes, remove the `headers.cookie` part. Sorry for the mistake, will also edit the example.

Comment: handshake.signedCookies is empty. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: The setting of the session middleware and the full authorization code.